# index.html doesn't save (using WebStorm, Yeoman, and Angular)

Tags: angularjs, yeoman, webstorm, bower

Edit: The problem occurs upon 'grunt serve' not upon closing and re-opening webstorm as I first suspected.

---

In the code block below, I manually added the ui-bootstrap.js files. The rest was scaffolded using Yeoman. When, index.html defaults back to its original state (removing the code I added). However, the rest of the project saves and reloads normally. What is causing this and how to I remedy it?

```
<!-- build:js scripts/vendor.js -->
<!-- bower:js -->
  <script src="bower_components/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/sass-bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
<!-- endbower -->
<!-- endbuild -->
```

Comment: Do you fire any scripts on start?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe this is because `grunt-bower-install` runs on `grunt serve`. Anything between `<!-- bower:js -->` and `<!-- endbower -->` is controlled by `grunt-bower-install`. That's the Grunt task that looks for dependencies from your Bower packages, and injects them into your HTML.

You can either do everything manually -- find and insert all the scripts you need in your HTML -- and remove `grunt-bower-install` (uninstall and remove from `Gruntfile.js`), or place some of your dependencies manually outside of the comment block.

Comment: Yes! This seems to be the problem. Adding my scripts outside of bower's block will work for now. Is there any way to add these scripts to bower's list to be injected?

Comment: There's actually a discussion about this going on at https://github.com/stephenplusplus/wiredep/issues/31. Feel free to weigh in! The answer for now is essentially, unfortunately, no. I believe we should ask for packages to play nicer with Bower than overdo it with the tooling.

Answer (score 0):

```
bower install angular-ui-bootstrap-bower
```

Can fix this problem.

The reason is that the lib you installed dosen't configure the main js file in the config file named "`bower_components/ui-bootstrap/bower.json`".

Comment: sorry, add '--save' at the end of the commond.if not ,it won't work